# href hashtag # makes modal popup gallery on click to jump on the top of the site

Tags: html, css, image-gallery, modalpopup

I am using an html5-css3 template with a modal popup gallery which jumps to the top of the site when I click on any image. It is because of the  hashtag and I have no idea how to get it work properly. Please help! I am new to coding and I searched for an answer for days now but didn't find a solution.

here is how the html code looks like:

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="#modal-01"><img src="images/portfolio/canandreu.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Comment: the code just didn't show up in the question: <a href="#" data-reveal-id="#modal-01"><img src="images/portfolio/canandreu.jpg" alt=""/></a>

Comment: Have you tried to use `preventDefault` function (https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) ?

Comment: no I haven't but I will try it, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a class like `modal-link` to each of the `a` tags, then you can use some code like this:

```
var modalLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-link');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(modalLinks, function(el, i){
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

This will prevent each of the elements with the class `modal-link` from jumping you to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `href="JavaScript:Void(0);"`

> By using `JavaScript:Void(0)`, you can eliminate the unwanted
>   side-effect, because it will return the undefined primitive value.

```
<a href="JavaScript:Void(0)" data-reveal-id="#modal-01"><img src="images/portfolio/canandreu.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Comment: thx for writing the whole line. It prevents the jump but the modal doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share your `modal` jQuery or javascript code

Comment: I would love to share it but it is pure css

Comment: @SlevinK I am not sure. How it can be pure css if you are trying to open a popup on click.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 

or

but i suggest use user onclick="return false;" this will fix your problem

Comment: actually now I tried again and it also prevents the jump but blocks the popup as the JavaScript:Void(0) thx anyways